# Axios, How to accelerate response performance?

Tags: vue.js, codeigniter, vuejs2, axios

I have problem with server response time on local project (I am using xampp to host it), it is beetwen 1.3s to 2s. It is pretty annoying, I have about 12 selects like this and all works slow as this. I think it should work much faster.

[Here's screen from network traffic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8XOh.png)

I am using vuejs (v2.6.12) with axios (v0.21.4), here's method to get vehicle data from backend:

```
getVehicleData231() {
    this.marki = [];

    axios
        .get('CommunicationPackage/getJsonVehiclesData231',{
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
        .then(response => {
            let data = response.data;
            console.log(data);
            this.marki = data;
        })
        .catch(error => {

        });
},
```

All I tried to do was select some data from database (MySql) and return it to Vue, I thought query was performance problem, so I turned it into echo with static array(actual code below). Response time didn't change.
My backend (CodeIgniter v3.1.11) function:

```
public function getJsonVehiclesData231()
{
    $arrayVar = [["name" => "ALFA ROMEO", "code" => "353"]];

    echo json_encode($arrayVar);
}
```

I searched the internet but didn't ran into anything helpful about slow server response. How could I shorten waiting time to for instance 50ms?

I tried axios with post and get, nothing changed.
At first I tried query from db and I thought it was the problem, but it is not.

I am expecting to get 50-100ms response time from server.

My device spec:
[image: pc_spec]

Comment: Please post TEXT of the last 50 lines of your MySQL Slow Query Log for analysis.  Once you post that, we will be able to ask you to provide TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name; for each table involved for analysis of missing indexes, if any.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I am not using database right now. As you can see, backend function return array with some data.

Comment: When you are using the database, we will try to assist.

Comment: Sir, I don't want to analyse my database. All I want to is find why I have to wait 1.5s for server response.

Comment: it's difficult to diagnose not knowing anything about the backend server.  is it hosted third party?  is it located far away?  does it have good hardware?

Comment: How big is the response in bytes? There's no length data in the question. Generally you need to isolate the problem to either front or back end. It looks that Vue is irrelevant and you could reformulate the question. You can check this with direct request to /CommunicationPackage/getJsonVehiclesData231 via address bar or Postman

Comment: Most people that want to know why they have to wait 1.5s for server response are using a database.  You opening comments indicated your data was hosted on MySQL. On 2024 03 07 14:53 you are NOT using database right now.  When you can provide the data requested 2024 03 07 about 14:42 we should be able to tell you where the missing indexes are causing the delay.  We will not analyze your database, just the one query and tables involved will be reviewed, looking for missing indexes.  If you WANT your database analyzed, this is not the place use dba.stackexchange.com for deeper look at your world.

Comment: @yoduh I updated question with my device spec, take a look. I am using win10, host project through xampp.